# FormData() adding character count to data

Tags: php, jquery, xmlhttprequest

So I am trying to simply POST data but for some reason it is showing up different then it should.

Example:

```
payload = new FormData();
payload.append('url', 'about');
```

To my knowledge when I try to `echo $_POST['url']` it should show `about` but instead it is showing `string(5) "about"` and I have no clue why.

I have spent almost an hour searching but can't find anything else about it. So I am hoping someone on here will know the answer.

Comment: have you used var_dump to print the the posted data? -  Please check once .

Comment: Yes I have and it still shows up the same way.

Comment: can you show the code from the file where you are echoing the string

Comment: Literally all I have on there is `$_POST['url']` and `var_dump($_POST)` because I was testing to make sure it worked before I uploaded it to a database but then this occurred.

Comment: It turns out it's doing it even on just a simple form no AJAX or anything. I don't know what is going on.

Comment: remove this line var_dump($_POST) of statement

Comment: Still it shows string(5) "about"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105539/discussion-between-alankar-more-and-nico-plyley).